# Partial view rendering issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

in my project i have one view which renders from viewmodel
view model contains the properties as follows

1. Model1

2.List of Model1

3.List of Model2

and my view has two partialviews , from controller i have pass the Viewmodel to mainview and in mainview i pass model1 to first partial view and List to second partialview

now in first partial view i want to render a dropdown with the values binded to List
How can i do this?

is there any explicit way to do this.
i cant change my model..........

Comment: Why can't you change you model? If you used a view model, which is the best practice, then you would had full control of what gets sent to and from a view.

Comment: You can always pass the whole model to your partials and do whatever you need to do there.

Comment: i am using code first approach for entityframework so if i change me model then unnecessorily i am loading database by duplicating entries of existing entities

Comment: and passing a whole viewmodel to both partial is conceptually wrong . . . . . .so i cant pass viewmodel to both partials

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to make the list go into partialView1 and cant change the model signature (which is what you should do), you can use @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") to go to an action that returns a partial view. This would likely incur an extra database trip.

To do it the correct way, you should change the partial view signature to accept the entire viewmodel, or at least a model that encompasses both List and  model1.